# Django/jQuery - autocomplete and dynamically updating form field values

Tags: jquery, django, forms

My data structure consists of two models, one of which is a foreign key of the other. I've been trying to construct a form for data entry but have been having difficulties.

Say my two models are Event and Venue and each has several fields, including name. What I would like to have is a form that has all the fields, for both models. The field Venue name should have an autocomplete that suggests existing Venues. If the user selects an existing Venue per the autocomplete suggestion, all the fields that are from the Venue model should get filled in and locked. If, however, the user enters a new Venue name, he should be able to fill in all the fields, and then both a new Event and a new Even will be created.

I hope that this makes sense. What would be the best way to implement something like this? Are there any useful existing extensions or would it be easier to write from scratch? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)